# Alt + . for last argument doesn't work

Tags: command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, dwm

To recall the argument of a previous shell command, in the past, with several distros and terminals, I've used those shorcuts:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> + <kbd>_</kbd>

Now that I'm using Artix with `dwm` and `st`, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> doesn't work (in both Bash and Zsh), only <kbd>Esc</kbd> + <kbd>_</kbd> does.

Since I'm facing the same issue with both `gnome-terminal` and `konsole`, always launched by `dmenu` from a `dwm` session, I don't think it's a problem of `st`, nor of Artix.

Maybe it's a `dwm` related issue? Does it intercept the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> combination (and does nothing)? Can I change its behaviour or do I risk to break its internal structure?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I answered myself:

`/usr/src/dwm/config.h`

From

```
#define MODKEY Mod1Mask
```

to

```
#define MODKEY Mod4Mask
```

then

`make clean install`

and reload `dwm`.

Now I'm "forced" to use the <kbd>Win</kbd> key instead of <kbd>Alt</kbd> for <kbd>Meta</kbd> (Mod1) in `dwm`, but in the terminal(s) now <kbd>Alt</kbd> behaves as expected.